# How to stop notification on particular condition

Tags: android, sqlite, notifications, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

My application is generating notifications on the basis of time stored in a database, it's like when the user hit the notification button, all the alarm will get set at the back and will generate notifications everyday, now the problem is when I'm pressing the notification button, it is generating notification immediately on pressing even though it's not the time of noti, I observed that it is due to time in the database. which is already passed like for eg. I press notification button at 2:30:00 but in my database there was a time of 2:28:00 stored, so it generates notification of that time. cause I have tested setting time later then current and it worked fine (like no notification is generated on the click).
So how to stop getting notification of previous time?

```
  for (int i = 0; i < C.getCount(); i++) {


        h[i] = Integer.valueOf(DealTimes[i].split(":")[0]);
        m[i] = Integer.valueOf(DealTimes[i].split(":")[1]);
        //   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Time at 16th index " + h + "min " + m, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h[i]);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m[i]);
        calendar.set(calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        A[i] = calendar.getTimeInMillis();


        //     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Final calnder Time in mili sec " + A[i] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Final calnder Only Time  " + calendar.getTime() + " Time zone " + calendar.getTimeZone(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Setting Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);

        final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, A[i],
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, _id, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,Allah[i],AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, _id, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));


    }
```

this is my broadcast receiver's code

```
         private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    SQLiteDB handler;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String myUserid = "1"; // = new SavedPreferences(context).getUserId();

        long[] blah = intent.getLongArrayExtra("id");
        handler = new SQLiteDB(context);
        handler.open();
        Cursor C = handler.returnData();

        String notificationUserId = intent.getStringExtra("NotificationUserId");
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(myUserid) && myUserid.equals(notificationUserId)) {
            String bookingId = intent.getStringExtra("bookingId");
            System.out.println("SP ID IN RECEIVER"+intent.getStringExtra("spId"));
            String spId = intent.getStringExtra("spId");
// change before using for real
            for (int i = 0; i <C.getCount(); i++) {
                if (new Date().getTime() > blah[i]) {//dbTime) {// Here time is past so need not to play notification.
                } else {// Notification time is in future. So can play the notification.
                    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    NOTIFICATION_ID = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("Id"));
                    mIntent.putExtra("message", intent.getStringExtra("message"));
                    mIntent.putExtra("Id", NOTIFICATION_ID);
                    mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 111, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
                    Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                    builder.setSound(uri);
                    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                    builder.setContentTitle("Test");
                    builder.setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("message"));
                    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cast_ic_notification_forward);
                    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                    //  builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(context.getString(R.string.service_completed_text)));
                    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate notification on exact time match then you can convert both time (current time and the previously stored time) into string and then you can easily use `String.Equals()` function. But in your current scenario, if the user presses the button after the stored time is passed then he would miss the notification. According to me, you should use `service` to generate notifications on the basis of time. Its just my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am posting an example for you. Please proceed step by step. It will really help.

1. Where you set the alarm, just use a custom broadcast receiver. I will mention the receiver code below.

   ```
   AlarmManager beforeAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   Intent alarmIntentBefore = new Intent(NotificationRequestActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                       alarmIntentBefore.putExtra("id", bookingId);
                       alarmIntentBefore.putExtra("message", "");

   PendingIntent pendingIntentBefore = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(NotificationRequestActivity.this,
                      111, alarmIntentBefore, 0);
   beforeAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, new Date().getTime(), pendingIntentBefore);
   ```
2. Now create an alarm receiver. **Here We will check if the alarm time is past then we will not generate the notification. Otherwise it will get generated.**

Create a `BroadcastReceiver` named as `AlarmReceiver.java`:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

   @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String myUserid = new SavedPreferences(context).getUserId();
        String notificationUserId = intent.getStringExtra("NotificationUserId");
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(myUserid) && myUserid.equals(notificationUserId)) {
            String bookingId = intent.getStringExtra("bookingId");
            System.out.println("SP ID IN RECEIVER"+intent.getStringExtra("spId"));
            String spId = intent.getStringExtra("spId");

            if (new Date().getTime() > dbTime) {// Here time is past so need not to play notification.
            } else {// Notification time is in future. So can play the notification.
                notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, RatingActivity.class);
                NOTIFICATION_ID = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("Id"));
                mIntent.putExtra("message", intent.getStringExtra("message"));
                mIntent.putExtra("Id", NOTIFICATION_ID);
                mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 111, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
                Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                builder.setSound(uri);
                builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                builder.setContentTitle("Test");
                builder.setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("message"));
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon);
                builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(context.getString(R.string.service_completed_text)));
                notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Register the alarm receiver in manifest.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but can you please explain me what is RatingActivity.class is for in your code? I have edited my me alert recvier with respect to yout code, it is mentioned in my question (edited). please have a look at it coz it is not working, now i'm not reciveeing any notification at all not even on correct time.